# How to add custom post types to Infinite theme (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme (Infinite theme) to make my website which has a built in page builder/editor.

I would like to override this and create my own custom post types to update the website in the future but the theme doesn't let me do this.
i know how to create custom post types,but have no idea how to integrate it in to the theme templates.

Can someone please advise a solution around this.  Many thanks!

Comment: The Wordpress Codex is your friend... https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use PHP code to do that. You can find examples in the [WP codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), but I strongly recommend using a tool like [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) for that, to make sure you're not forgetting anything.

Then, you'll need to edit your theme files. The best practice is to create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) (optional but recommended to prevent code loss when updating the theme) and put the code in the `functions.php` file (using either FTP or the WordPress built-in theme editor).

Small note: you can not do this with wordpress.com hosted websites, currently.